# Atom Packages & Themes export process?

Tags: atom-editor

I use atom text editor quite often at work and also at home for my own side projects to improve as a developer. Occasionally I'll come across a better theme or a new package to automate some part of my work and then have trouble finding it to update my other  machine.

Is there a way to generate an export file or log that contains your themes and package details? It'd be really nice if I could pull that data every so often just to make sure both my machines are kept in sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [several packages](https://atom.io/packages/search?q=package+sync) available for package synchronizing, you need to find the one that suits your needs bests (also StackOverflow discourages opinionated answers)

Alternatively, you could always use services such as Dropbox. Simply create a symlink inside your Dropbox folder pointing to the `.atom` folder.

**Example:**

```
$ mkdir ~/Dropbox/DotAtom
$ ln -s ~/Dropbox/DotAtom ~/.atom
```

Comment: Thanks this helps a ton. I was thinking of this all wrong

Comment: Adding this as a comment. If anyone else is looking for a good package-sync tool I used https://atom.io/packages/package-sync it basically makes a cson from which you can install any missing packages for a new setup